# After for-loop creating Element and add function, all children get changed by last loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick, appendchild

I just to want to see:  click link0, alert 0, click linkn, alert n.
But in my code, whichever link I click, the alert is n.

SO in this case, I can see link0 link1 ... link4,
but whichever link I click , it alerts 5.

Body is empty

Javascript code is as follows:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    var link =   document.createElement("a");


    link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;

    link.onclick =function(){alert(i)};

    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example   same quesiton from here

Comment: the problem is that the variable i, within each of your anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the inside of the loop in a closure.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.innerHTML = "Link " + index;
    link.onclick = function() {
      alert(index)
    };
    document.body.appendChild(link);
  })(i);
}
```

```css
a { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks,  I found the from the same question,  someone mentioned that using let instead of var would solve the problem quickly